# Output of IsomorphicGraphQ

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Is it same for newer versions of Mathematica that `IsomorphicGraphQ` has problems with multiple self-connected edges?

```
$Version
{Graph[{1}, UndirectedEdge @@@ {{1, 1}}, ImageSize -> Tiny, 
  PlotRangePadding -> None], 
 Graph[{2}, UndirectedEdge @@@ {{2, 2}}, ImageSize -> Tiny, 
  PlotRangePadding -> None]}
IsomorphicGraphQ @@ %

{Graph[{1}, UndirectedEdge @@@ {{1, 1}, {1, 1}}, ImageSize -> Tiny, 
  PlotRangePadding -> None], 
 Graph[{2}, UndirectedEdge @@@ {{2, 2}, {2, 2}}, ImageSize -> Tiny, 
  PlotRangePadding -> None]}
IsomorphicGraphQ @@ %
```

---

[image]

Comment: [Yes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkNMz.png).

Comment: Surprisingly, if I change `IsomorphicGraphQ @@ %` to `FindGraphIsomorphism @@ %`, the result is `{<| 1 -> 2 |>}`. And yet `CanonicalGraph[Graph[{1}, UndirectedEdge @@@ {{1, 1}, {1, 1}}]` returns the same error. Do these results demonstrate a bug?

Comment: @creidhne Yes, I think it is a bug.

Comment: @creidhne By the way you can post it as an answer as a workaround. If `FindGraphIsomorphism` outputs some rule then the graphs are isomorphic if it returns `{}` they are not isomorphic.

Comment: I don't think this is necessary a _bug_. `*Q` functions are guaranteed to give an answer, and if the general method isn't implemented, they cannot ensure an answer, hence an error message. `Find*` functions on the other hand only attempt to find a solution, and they can fail to do so.

Comment: @Domen But if `FindGraphIsomorphism` finds an isomorphisms it must be able to decide whether it is indeed isomorphism so there is no reason why `FindGraphIsomorphism` should be able to do it but `IsomorphicGraphQ` should not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`FindGraphIsomorphism`](https://reference.wolframcloud.com/cloudplatform/ref/FindGraphIsomorphism.html) returns an empty list if no isomorphism can be found, so it can function as a workaround when `IsomorphicGraphQ` fails.

```
$Version
(* 14.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (December 13, 2023) *)
```

Here are two examples:

```
FindGraphIsomorphism @@ {
 Graph[{1}, UndirectedEdge @@@ {{1, 1}, {1, 1}}], 
 Graph[{2}, UndirectedEdge @@@ {{2, 2}, {2, 2}}]} =!= {}
(* True *)
```

```
FindGraphIsomorphism @@ {
 Graph[{1}, UndirectedEdge @@@ {{1, 1}, {1, 1}}], 
 Graph[{2}, UndirectedEdge @@@ {{2, 2}, {2, 1}}]} =!= {}
(* False *)
```

---

**An observation about `IsomorphicGraphQ`**

Here are two graphs that are not isomorphic; `IsomorphicGraphQ` detects the condition and gives `False`.

```
IsomorphicGraphQ @@ {
 Graph[{1}, UndirectedEdge @@@ {{1, 1}, {1, 1}}], 
 Graph[{2}, UndirectedEdge @@@ {{2, 2}, {2, 1}}]}
(* False *)
```

However, these next two graphs are isomorphic, but `IsomorphicGraphQ` causes the error, which shows the self-loop problem in azerbajdzan's question.

```
IsomorphicGraphQ @@ {
 Graph[{1}, UndirectedEdge @@@ {{1, 1}, {1, 1}}], 
 Graph[{2}, UndirectedEdge @@@ {{2, 2}, {2, 2}}]}
(* IsomorphicGraphQ::ngen *)
```

Answer (score 6):

The IGraph/M package supports isomorphism checking for multigraphs. See `IGIsomorphicQ`.